# python is not allowing to access back variable value set in exec

Tags: python-3.x

```
>>> def fn(sc):
...     exec(sc)
```

This function runs perfectly fine.

Comment: The answer is still the same: either add `global` statements, explicitly reference `globals()['A4'] = A4 + 1`, or tell `exec()` what local namespace to update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that executing `"A4 = A4+1"` inside `fn` without indicating that `A4` is a global doesn't affect the global variable, since each function has its own local dictionary of variables.

If you need your `fn` to be a separate function containing an `exec` call, you can specify that your variable is a global, using the `global` keyword.

```
>>> def fn(sc):
...   exec(sc)
...
>>> value = 1
>>> fn('value += 1')
>>> value
1
>>> fn('global value; value += 1')
>>> value
2
```

Alternatively, `exec` will accept explicit `globals` and `locals` dictionaries passed into it. The help info for these functions notes that you can't reliably alter the value of a variable by updating `locals()`, but you *can* with `globals()`. As long as globals are what you want to update, you don't need to pass `locals()`.

```
>>> def fn(sc):
...   exec(sc, globals())
...
>>> value = 1
>>> fn('value += 1')
>>> value
2
```

Comment: Presumably the OP simplified it down to only call `exec()`. And clearly `fn` is not just an alias, since the namespace targets are different.

Comment: @khelwood  what is the impact, if I pass fn("...", globals(), globals())  It seems to work

Comment: @TooGeeky If you're not inside a function, then there are no local variables, so `locals()` and `globals()` return the same thing. As long as you only want to alter global variables, passing `globals()` as both dictionaries should work.

Comment: @khelwood Perfect :) Thanks ... At last, there are some people genuinely to help on stackoverflow ... instead of just pressing down down(-1) button and marking it duplication. Appreciate the effort.

Comment: You're welcome. It was interesting to try out.